# Round Numbers Evenly

Tags: objective-c, math, ios5

How do I round numbers up or down depending on the value in object C.. for example.

Lets say the number is 143 - I would want to round down to 140
but if the number is 146 - I would want to round up to 150

any suggestions?

Comment: what is the condition for rounding up ? I mean 146 is also a even number, then what you really need ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming 145 should round to 150 (that's the standard in science and technology), the formula is:

```
x_rounded = ((x + 5)/10)*10;
```

More generally, when rounding to the nearest n, it's

```
x_rounded = ((x + n/2)/n)*n;
```

It comes from the fact that integer division always rounds down.

For negative numbers, it's slightly more tricky.

EDIT: also assuming it's all integers. With floats/doubles, better use the C math library, as division works differently. Like this:

```
#include <math.h>

x_rounded = floor((x+5)/10) * 10;
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! thank you. x_rounded = floor((x+5)/10) * 10;

Answer (score 1):

Round value x to precision p, where 0 < p < infinite. (f.ex. p=0.25, 0.5, 1, 2, 3, 10,…)

```
float RoundTo(float x, float p)
{
  float y = 1/p;
  return int((x+(1/(y+y)))*y)/y;
}
float RoundUp(float x, float p)
{
  float y = 1/p;
  return int((x+(1/y))*y)/y;
}
float RoundDown(float x, float p)
{
  float y = 1/p;
  return int(x*y)/y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `lround` function will round a float to the nearest integer. You can fairly easily get it to round to a multiple of 10 by dividing the number by 10, rounding, then multiplying by 10.

in code:

```
10 * lround(x / 10.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think the simplest solution would be to include math.h and use the round() function.

Comment: I always use roundf/floorf but I don't remember needing to #include math.h (Xcode)

Comment: It likely depends on what kind of project you're working on. I just tried to make a command-line tool project in Xcode, and I had to include it in main.c in order to use the round() function. You have to include it _somewhere_ I assume, so maybe the project types you're working on have files that include it for you somewhere.

Comment: Right... I only coded iOS/Mac apps on Xcode. But in standard C you must include math.h, stdlib.h, etc... I guess Foundation.h and/or UIKit.h conveniently includes all those for you.

Answer (score 0):

For rounding floats to nearby integer values, check out the C functions floorf(), ceilf() and roundf().

For rounding integers to (say), the closest multiple of ten, the formula given by Seva should work...

Answer (score 0):

This will definitely solve your worries.

```
- (int) roundToNearest5:(int) value
{         
   return (value+(5-(value%5));         
}
```